Как отсорировать вложенные кортежи с координатами по значениям координат?
Например, есть список с координатами двух точек на прямой, он отсортирован по возрастанию расстояния между точками.
a = [(-1, -3), (2, 3), (5, 9), (-4, 4)]

У координат (-1, -3) и (2, 3) расстояния между точками равны. Их необходимо отсортировать по возрастанию значения координаты первой точки, затем по возрастанию значения второй точки.
Т.е на выходе надо получить:
[(2, 3), (-1, -3), (5, 9), (-4, 4)]

Спасибо!

Расстояния между какими точками? Непонятно.

"У координат (-1, -3) и (2, 3) расстояния между точками равны." Или не понимаю или не верю.

sorted(a, key=lambda p: (abs(p[0] - p[1]), *p)).

действительно. я обсчитался

a = [(-1, -3), (2, 3), (5, 9), (-4, 4)]
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x:abs(x[1]-x[0]))
print(b)


[(2, 3), (-1, -3), (5, 9), (-4, 4)]

